# How to select multiple CSS parent and descendant groups efficiently

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a more efficient way to select multiple parent and descendant groups?

What I have now:

```
aside p, aside h1, aside h2, aside h3, aside h4,
article p, article h1, article h2, article h3, article h4,
section p, section h1, section h2, section h3, section h4 {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you add your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### :matches()

You can use the [`:matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:matches) CSS pseudo-class function to group your parents and descendants:

```
:matches(aside, article, section) :matches(p, h1, h2, h3, h4)
```

Note that, at the time of writing, this is still an experimental technology, so you may want to view the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:matches#Browser_compatibility) before using this in production.

Older browsers may require using the vendor-prefixed pseudo-class `:any()`:

```
:-moz-any(aside, article, section) :-moz-any(p, h1, h2, h3, h4),
:-webkit-any(aside, article, section) :-webkit-any(p, h1, h2, h3, h4),
:matches(aside, article, section) :matches(p, h1, h2, h3, h4)
```

According to [CSSWG issue #3258](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3258), `:matches()` might be renamed to `:is()` in the future:

```
:is(aside, article, section) :is(p, h1, h2, h3, h4)
```

Comment: Has indeed been renamed to [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#browser_compatibility) and is no longer marked as experimental, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all the tag specificity.

```
p, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
width: 75%;
padding: 15px 0;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure CSS, your current way is probably the most efficient means, other than setting a class on all the h tags.

Using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you could do something like this:

```
aside, article, section {
  h1, h2, h3, h4 { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if there are only (p, h1-h4) in parents you can do that:

```
aside > *, article > *, section > * {
width: 75%;
padding: 15px 0;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

it will affect only direct children.

Comment: Interesting!  Similarly, I could use:  aside * without the > for all descendants, correct?

Comment: That's right. But you should remember about selectors priority - if there are some css property for p#inAside - the previous will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The most performant, concise and specific selector would simply be:

```
.selector {
    width: 75%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

it could be opinable that it will pollute your markup but in pure terms of css performance this is it.

with regards to `*` selector, its performance is poor and adding a parent selector will NOT improve the situation, as [illustrated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Writing_Efficient_CSS#How_the_Style_System_Matches_Rules)

> The style system matches rules by starting with the key selector, then moving to the left (looking for any ancestors in the rule’s selector). As long as the selector’s subtree continues to check out, the style system continues moving to the left until it either matches the rule, or abandons because of a mismatch.

one last remark, `aside, article, section` are not supported in IE < 8 so any styling won't be picked up by those browsers (unless a polyfill is used but that is a JS only way)

Comment: Brilliant.  I don't know why I did not see this.

Comment: I have the default modernizr from H5BP, would that polyfill the aside, article, section, etc?

Comment: I think it must since my page does style correclty in IE7 & IE8.

Comment: yes, modernizr already includes a script similar to other html5shim/html5shiv libraries, so no need to do anything else!

Comment: downvotes without a comment/argument always baffled me!